# Return Number Not String In Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

This is my SQL syntax and (this is only a snippet unfortunately I am stuck running dynamic SQL in this instance) - but my issue is at the very end of my statement when I do the `Select @numreturned` what is returned is the SQL statement NOT the actual number that is returned when I run the `Exec(@numreturned)`

What must I alter in order to return the NUMBER instead of the SQL Statement?

```
Declare @numreturned varchar(max), 
@fulllocation varchar(max) = 'nagadishi.mirama.dbo.Humizan'

Set @numreturned = 'Select Count(*) FROM '+@fulllocation+' '
                   +'WHERE ([Nishan] IS NULL) '

Print @numreturned
Exec(@numreturned)

Select @numreturned
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with `sp_executesql` and assigning the variable to an output parameter

```
DECLARE @numreturned  INT;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @fulllocation NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'nagadishi.mirama.dbo.Humizan';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @numreturned = COUNT(*) FROM '+@fulllocation+' '
                   +N'WHERE ([Nishan] IS NULL)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@numreturned INT OUTPUT', @numreturned = @numreturned OUTPUT;
SELECT @numreturned;
```